# Load sharing MOSFET problem

Tags: mosfet, load

This is the schematic of the circuit:
[image]
Power-supply1 is an external supply.
Power-supply2 is a 3S Li-ion battery.
**AIM OF THE CIRCUIT: When an external power supply is connected, the load should draw current from the external power supply. So MOSFET should be turned-off in this situation.**
Power supply-1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdQ13.jpg
Power supply-2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH3bf.jpg
The circuit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPoUO.jpg
**PROBLEM DEFINITION:**
When the output voltage of the P.S.1 is 13V, load draw current from P.S.1 (as expected)
When the output voltage of the P.S.1 is 12V, load draw current from P.S.2 (not desired)
[image]
*In the second case, although the G-S voltage is 0.1V, why does the MOSFET open and the current is drawn from power supply 2?

In case of an external power source, the current must be drawn from the external source.*
Note: G-S threshold value of the P-channel MOSFET between -2V and -4V from the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. But you need to drive the P-channel MOSFET in a way that turns off the battery regardless of input voltage.
You can do this by thinking of the V1 as a signal for switching input.

When V1 is on it drives both the output through D1 and the base of Q2. This turns Q2 off, so there is 0V across Vgs of M1.
When V1 is low/open, then Q2 turns on which puts ~6V across Vgs of M1, which allows V2 to supply power to the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp7v4z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

UPDATE:

> *But I have to know the root reason about the problem.*

1. The body diode in your circuit is always forward biased. So even if you did turn off the PMOS FET, the diode would still conduct.
   Notice in my circuit that the M1 source pin is connected to V2. This makes the diode point to V2, thus blocking current from V2 when the FET is off.
2. To turn on a PMOS FET, you have to put a voltage from the gate to the source greater in magnitude than the Vgs threshold voltage.
   This is what R1, R2 are doing.  There is a negative 6V (referenced to the source pin)developed across R2.
   In your circuit you **never** put a negative voltage on the gate.

Comment: Can you explain the circuit? Where is the V1?

Comment: @berker I renamed the power supplies to match your circuit.

Comment: @berker Updated the schematic and description.  The initial design was flawed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i have to know the root reason about the problem. I don't have a big chance to change PCB layout, i just make only small modifications like changing mosfet or adding one small component.

Comment: @berker I added some comparisons/explanations between our circuits

Comment: How can i handle with small modificaitons? I wish, I could reach your circuit before making plenty of PCB.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [datasheet for the IRF4905](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf4905pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e329b1197e) and note the body diode.

Comment: I've checked it. But in the 13V case, the diode still is there. But the circuit works and mosfet turns-off.

Comment: Also, VGS is still positive.